# Is there any way to run multiple nodes on Ethereum?

Tags: dapps

Does anyone know that how to run multiple nodes on one PC in private test network?
like running several Ethereum Wallets which could be used for testing contract or transfers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code you can create a network on your PC:

```
geth --networkid 13 --port 60303 --rpc --lightkdf --cache 16 --datadir "D:\bolckchain\chaindata" console
```

This code miens `D:\bolckchain\chaindata` genesis file init and database datadir

This code you run and check the private network :

$ `admin`

```
Then Network id : 13;
```

and help link this

[This link try](https://medium.com/taipei-ethereum-meetup/beginners-guide-to-ethereum-2-run-multiple-nodes-on-a-private-network-in-5-lines-c97a4d78a590)

Please try it

Thanks you